# Creating a citation section in an access report

Tags: sql, ms-access, reporting-services, reporting

I currently have a report that is broken out by:

Report Header (not used)

Page Header

Owner Header

Detail Section

Owner Footer

Page Footer

Report Footer (not used)

The detail section of the report lists out all of the products owned by a specific owner, data which is pulled from a table.

Some of these products have a special nuance to them that need to be documented. I have created a query that isolates all the products and their owners that fit this criteria.

How do I post the data from this query to the owner section of the report and make sure that this data references the products in the detail section of the report? - Akin to a citation table.

Comment: Sorry not a full answer but check out a subreport. You can plop your citations where ever you need to if you put them in another report.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll look into that now.